# Laravel: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.pages doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, migrate

I'm working on a CMS and I have a little problem with my migrations. I added a new migration file and I wanted to add that one. That didn't work so I ran this bit:

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

After that I ran this bit:

```
php artisan migrate:install
php artisan migrate
```

And now I get this error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or 
view not found:1146 Table 'cms.pages' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `pages`)"
```

The error kinda tells me that it can't find the database, because that's true.

I also have a command that runs the migrate and I run that one like this:

```
php artisan app:install
```

But that shows the same error...

Comment: do you have any custom service providers added to `app/config/app.php`? They still run during artisan commands, and if one of them depends on the pages table existing you will run into this situation.

Comment: Nop, I don't... I did made my own SiteServiceProvider: <?php namespace App\Site;

class SiteServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider {

 public function boot()
 {
  $this->package('app/site', 'site', public_path() . '/site');
 }

 public function register()
 {
  require public_path() . '/site/routes.php';
 }

}

Comment: unless you explicitly added it to the app config, it won't be included. another possibility would be something added to `bootstrap/start.php`, `app/start/global.php`, `app/start/local.php` or `app/routes.php` that is looking for that table

Comment: I do use the laravel-menu provider and I generate a menu out of pages in my app/routes.php, can that be it?

Comment: yes, the routes still get processed even during artisan commands.  thats how `$ php artisan routes` knows the routes :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove any lines requesting data from your model from these files to be sure artisan is not trying to load data from your non-existent table:

- `bootstrap/start.php`
- `app/start/global.php`
- `app/start/local.php`
- `app/routes.php`

Also be sure to un-register any service providers that utilize data from that table in their register or boot methods inside of `app/config/app.php`.

---

The issue is that these files not only get executed for browser (web) requests, but for *all* requests, including command-line artisan invocations (e.g. `php artisan migrate`).  So if you try to use something before it is available in any of these files, you are going to have a Bad Time.

Comment: Let me try this out :D

Comment: Well that's the answer :D Thanks man! Do you have any idea how I can prevent this in the future with my laravel/menu (this is the repository: https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu)

Comment: Perhaps, I haven't looked too deeply at that, but I would define a generic 'Page' route only, with parameters to the route and let the controller that route points to fetch data from the model. I would register the menus in a service provider. you would still have to unregister that service provider when you need to migrate from scratch again, but its a lot less destructive than clearing out your routes, imho.

Comment: Your suggestion pointed me in the right direction.  My issue was I was referencing a Model in the AuthServiceProvider before the table existed.

Comment: thanks man it works, in my case (L5) i requesting data from `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

Comment: I am having a bad time with this

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to dictate when your app is running from the console. 
I believe this issue only occurs when you run a command

```
if( !App::runningInConsole() ){
  //allow laravel-menu to run
}
```

This way you will  prevent data load from your non-existent table