# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.ken_permissions' doesn't exist

Tags: laravel

Sometimes, when I type :

```
php artisan 
php artisan migrate
etc
```

I get the message:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.ken_permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `ken_permissions`)
```

Debugging, I can tell my problem happens in the artisan file in:

```
$status = $kernel->handle(
$input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput,
new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput
);
```

I had already check this answer, and didn't work:

bootstrap/app.php is clean,

I don't have app/start folder ( L5.1),

routes.php is clean

php artisan -v or php artisan --pretend doesn't work, because artisan fails before running it seems.

The only thing I have is in app/Providers

```
    public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    parent::registerPolicies($gate);
    // Dynamically register permissions with Laravel's Gate.
    foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        $gate->define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) {
            return $user->hasPermission($permission);
        });
    }
}
```

One solution is to delete all my tables, then composer dump-autoload, and then it work again, but it constantly comes back.

Is it a way to trace what migration is failing?
Any idea why is it happening?

Tx!

Comment: Pleases refer watcher's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25315591/4632218)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the App\Provider\AuthServiceProvider
if you use on boot method  GateContract ($this->getPermission() etc), remove or add to comment all after `parent::registerPolicies($gate);` and done run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to watcher's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315325/laravel-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-database-pages-doesnt-exist/25315591#25315591)

```
Remove any lines requesting data from your model from these files to be sure artisan is not trying to load data from your non-existent table:

bootstrap/start.php
app/start/global.php
app/start/local.php
app/routes.php
Also be sure to un-register any service providers that utilize data from that table in their register or boot methods inside of app/config/app.php.
```

You can move your migrations to a `database/temp folder` and run your migrations one by one 
`php artisan migrate --path=database/temp`
you will know which migration is causing problem.

**NOTE**
Also you can use 
`php artisan migrate --pretend` to get the query you are trying to do.

Comment: did you try moving the migrations to temp folder?